# $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ st $|f'(x)| \le 5$ , show that $\langle f(\frac{1}{n+1})$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ be  a differentiable function st $|f'(x)| \le 5 \forall x \in (0,1)$ , show that $\langle f(\frac{1}{n+1})\rangle$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

Derivative is bounded $\implies$ $f$ is uniform continuous on $(0,1) \implies$ $f$ takes cauchy sequence to cauchy seqeunce$\implies$ $\langle f(\frac{1}{n+1})\rangle$ is cauchy $\implies$ convergent

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I'd like to know whether my proof is correct or not

Comment: Your proof is completely correct. Maybe you should mention the mean value theorem for concluding that $f$ is Lipschitz, hence uniformly continuous.